# Want a .Net Socket Event Handler for incoming data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm rewriting an ancient VB6 program in C# (.Net Framework 4.0).    It communicates with a piece of industrial equipment on the factory floor.   VB6 used some old COM-based socket software; I'm using the .Net Socket class.

When I send a message to the equipment I expect a response back so I know to listen for one then.  But the equipment can also send messages **asynchronously** without warning (say, to indicate a failure or problem). So I **always** have to receive those.     So what I'd really like is an event handler that gets called whenever anything comes in from the equipment.

The Socket class seems to use a BeginReceive/EndReceive scheme for receive event handling.   Can I just do a BeginReceive once at the start of my program to define an event-handler for all incoming messages, or do I have to constantly be doing BeginReceive/EndReceive's throughout my program?

Thanks in advance for clarifying the correct way to do this.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I'm trying to understand how the Socket class intends events like this to be handled.   Unless I'm misreading it the MSDN makes it seem like you're expected to call BeginReceive anew each time, whereas I'm looking for an event handler that I declare once and events just keep coming in on it as long as I'm connected.   Is there such a thing with the Socket class?

Comment: No idea why this had been downvoted:  
It's so well written that the provided answer not only solves this, but also my problem I was about to post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you the server?

If you are the server, you will listen for a socket connection, and then accept the socket connection and store it. You will then call `BeginReceive` with the stored socket. In the `BeginReceive` method, you will provide a callback function to receive, and handle the data.

Once you receive data, the callback happens. The callback function will call `EndReceive` on the stored connection. This is where you get/handle the data. You will also call `BeginReceive` again to wait for more data.

This way, the `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` will run in a circle: you are always receiving data, and waiting for more data.

[Here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx):

```
void WaitForData(SocketState state)
{
  try
  {
    state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.DataBuffer, 0, state.DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadDataCallback), state);
  }
  catch (SocketException se)
  {
    //Socket has been closed  
    //Close/dispose of socket
  }
}

public void ReadDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  SocketState state = (SocketState)ar.AsyncState;
  try
  {
    // Read data from the client socket.
    int iRx = state.Socket.EndReceive(ar);

    //Handle Data....
    WaitForData(state);
  }
  catch (ObjectDisposedException)
  {
    //Socket has been closed  
    //Close/dispose of socket
  }
  catch (SocketException)
  {
    //Socket exception
    //Close/dispose of socket
  }
}
```

EDIT: 
As per your comment, here is an example of a C# asynchronous client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx.

The `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` work similar to the server.

Comment: Is BeginReceive also called inside the callback function?    What is the purpose of calling EndReceive? Isn't the callback function reentrant?    If I call EndReceive then do some stuff then call BeginReceive again what happens to data that comes in while I'm doing the stuff?

Comment: Yes, BeginReceive is called in the callback function. EndRecieve will get the data from the receive. In your callback: You call EndReceive, then handle data and then call BeginReceive.

Comment: re "Are you the server?"   The PC initiates the connection, the equipment just listens for one, although both the PC and factory equipment can initiate data transmission without being prompted by the other.   So I think that makes the PC the client.

Comment: I added an example of a simple beginReceive/EndReceive

Comment: But why is it necessary to call EndReceive?    I don't know VB6 but it looks like the old code was using some 3rd-party version of WinSock and in that code once they set up their event handler it just ran - there was no need to stop it and start it again.

Comment: The C# code that I am explaining and the examples linked are for asynchronous sockets. Your must use BeginReceive/EndReceive to perform the socket operations asynchronously. If you do not want to use asynchronous sockets then you could use sychronous sockets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/kb5kfec7.aspx.